# Is wan ip for every node unique?

Tags: ip

As for lan  though DHCP can give right ip's and even one can assign static ip ressembling subnet mask and gatway but that is in a small area.
So, i was curious that how come the wan ip be unique in the whole big world.By that i mean cant there be any two wan ip's same in the world, how do two ISP's or NSP's know that they shouldn't use that ip as it is being used by another, do they tell each other or is there any order or classes they use.

Answer (score 3):

WAN IPs may or may not be unique; the distinction is based on terminology. Public IPs must be unique, but a WAN is not necessarily public.

@heavyd provided the correct answer regarding **PUBLIC** IP addresses. They must be unique world-wide, and are arranged in a semi-geophysical hierarchy, so that route aggregation between large scale networks (known as AS's or [Autonomous Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_%28Internet%29)) which can represent entire states or nation-states, can be performed efficiently.

The distinction here though, is the definition of the term WAN. Every router has a LAN and a WAN side. The networks they connect to however, do not necessarily need to be public.

When I connect to my ISP for instance, the ISP is on the WAN side of my router. However, if I dig into my cablemodem config, I can see that the ISP uses a private 10.x.y.z network internally. To me that network is WAN, but to them it is LAN. When my packets exit their network (the WAN from their perspective), they are routed to the public internet, and it is at that point that my Public IP address manifests. The ISP/Carrier can use all kinds of tricks like [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), and other forms of Address sharing to proxy my connections, so it is entirely possible for them to run large numbers of private customers using few public addresses. Cell phone providers do this all the time.

Just as ISPs and Nation-States public networks are within a wider AS, so too are all WANs LANs from the right perspective.

Comment: +1 Good answer. Just to give some perspective read [this](http://www.nationalreview.com/corner/395292/north-korea-has-fewer-ip-addresses-new-york-city-block-patrick-brennan).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, every public IP address on the Internet must be unique.  This fact is the basis behind the [IPv4 address exhaustion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_address_exhaustion) problem we have been facing for the past few years, and the reason we're switching to IPv6.

IP addresses are controlled by [ICANN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICANN).  ICANN delegates groups of IP addresses to [regional internet registries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_registry) (ARIN, RIPE NCC, APNIC, LACNIC, and AfriNIC) which companies can contact to be allocated IP addresses.